# Format results in sql management studio

Tags: sql, formatting, ssms

Is it possible in some way to format the results of a query, like changing for example the background color of a selected row of the result to higlight negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - SQL Server Management Studio is a tool to manipulate data and SQL queries - not a presentation tool.

If you need to highlight or color cells, you're best bet is to export your result grid into Excel and apply those formatting rules there.

Comment: Yup. Or use SQL Server Reporting Services, which is entirely designed for formatting SQL results in a variety of ways.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx